# Xamarin equivalent of stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've always found this method highly convenient.  Is there a Xamarin equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("TestData/ReadMe.txt");
```

See the [Load a File](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/file_system/load_a_file/) documentation on the Xamarin site.